# concatenate 'str' and 'list' objects

Tags: python

im trying to get a simple xbmc addon working. it scrapes a list of youtube videos:

```
match=re.compile('<iframe title="YouTube video player" width="640" height="395" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/(.+?)?rel=0"').findall(link)
```

i then need to add the following to each 'match':

plugin://plugin.video.youtube/?path=/root/video&action=play_video&videoid=

so then match would be for example:

plugin://plugin.video.youtube/?path=/root/video&action=play_video&videoid=OAVuKPFKrNo

i have tried:

```
url=("plugin://plugin.video.youtube/?path=/root/video&action=play_video&videoid="+match)
```

but obviously it doesnt work. i am a beginner so go easy please

Comment: Ok, "doesnt work" is not enough information ;).

Comment: It does work - strings can be concatenated with + in python. Your 'match' can be not a string though - have you tried printing it?

Comment: Have you tried printing match? How does it look like?

Comment: the error i recieved was: TypeError: cannot concatenate 'str' and 'list' objects

Answer (score 0):

solved it with

```
url=("plugin://plugin.video.youtube/?path=/root/video&action=play_video&videoid="+match[0])
```

simple little change, is there a better way to do it thouugh?

Comment: findall returns a list. So, you need to get element of that list (even when there is only one element in it)

Comment: Is there just one element found? The list is of size one? If the answer is yes, I'd say your solution is perfectly acceptable.

Answer (score 0):

`re.compile('<iframe title="YouTube video player" width="640" height="395" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/(.+?)?rel=0"').findall()` returns a list. You are correct that you can not concatenate strings and lists.

You can do:

```
"plugin://plugin.video.youtube/?path=/root/video&action=play_video&videoid="+match[0]
```

Or:

```
'plugin://plugin.video.youtube/?path=/root/video&action=play_video&videoid={}'.format(*match)
```

Which unpacks the list.

Answer (score 0):

```
match = re.compile('<iframe title="YouTube video player" width="640" height="395" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/(.+?)?rel=0"').findall(link)
for m in match:
    url = ("plugin://plugin.video.youtube/?path=/root/video&action=play_video&videoid=" + m)
    # ... perform other actions on the URL
```

> This should give you all the matches one at a time

Comment: A `foreach` loop doesn't exist in python. It's just `for m in match`